# Merging rows based on adjacent row cell values

Tags: python, pandas

I have df that have sometimes (not always) rows with empty cell except one:

```
 |    A  |      B|    C|
0|  white|    one|    1|
1|       |       |    2|
2|  blue |    two|    3|
3|       |       |    4|
4|       |       |    5|
5|  black|  three|    6|
6|  brown|   four|    7|
```

What I want to accomplish is merging rows which have empty column 'A' and 'B' with previous row. Output should look like that:

```
 |    A  |      B|     C|
0|  white|    one|   1 2|
2|  blue |    two| 3 4 5|
5|  black|  three|     6|
6|  brown|   four|     7|
```

Possible combination are:

- no adjacent row with empty cells (row 5, 6)
- one adjacent row with empty cells (row 0, 1)
- more than one adjacent row with empty cells (row 2 - 4)

When this is simple case when every other row have empty cells I can manage this with something like this:

```
df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//2).sum()
```

But I can't figure out other/combined situations.

Thanks for help.

**UPDATE:**

As it came out after trying provided solution df have also situations like this one:

```
 |      A|    B|    C
0|  white|  one|    1
1|       |     |    2
2|  white|  one|    3
3|       |     |    4
4|       |     |    5
5|  white|  one|    6
6|  white|  one|    7
```

on such data provided solution gives following results:

```
 |      A|    B|       C
0|       |     |   2 4 5
1|  white|  one| 1 3 6 7
```

while expected should be like this:

```
 |      A|    B|    C
0|  white|  one|  1 2
2|  white|  one|3 4 5
5|  white|  one|    6
6|  white|  one|    7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use something like:

```
df.groupby(df.A.ffill()).agg({'B':'first','C':lambda x: ','.join(map(str,x))}).reset_index()
```

Even better (thanks to @piRSquared):

```
df.astype({'C': str}).ffill().groupby(['A', 'B']).C.apply(' '.join).reset_index()
```

---

If order is to be kept as the original df, try:

```
m=df.groupby(df.A.ffill()).agg({'B':'first','C':lambda x: ','.join(map(str,x))}).\
                                                reindex(df.A.dropna().unique())
m=m.reset_index()
print(m)
```

---

```
       A      B      C
0  white    one    1,2
1   blue    two  3,4,5
2  black  three      6
3  brown   four      7
```

**Note** replace the spaces with `np.nan` before doing this

**EDIT:**

Based on your update you can do:

```
df=df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True) #to replace whitespaces to NaN(optional)
new_df=(df.astype({'C': str}).groupby(df['A'].notnull().cumsum())
      .agg({'A':'first','B':'first','C':' '.join}).reset_index(drop=True))
print(new_df)
```

---

```
         A      B      C
0    white    one    1 2
1    white    one  3 4 5
2    white    one      6
3    white    one      7
```

Comment: `ffill` such a good idea! `df.astype({'C': str}).ffill().groupby(['A', 'B']).C.apply(' '.join).reset_index()`

Comment: @piRSquared Thanks Sir. :) Will update this elegant one in a bit.

Comment: I have quite extensive df, but anyway something is wrong since those solutions are not quite work. Maybe it's something in my dataset that I'm missing (already I found out that those 'empty' rows have duplicates between them selfs.

Comment: Sure, no complains here. I see that I got partial results on my data set. It seems like it's adding information to 'empty' rows (I wanted vice versa) and drop duplicates (groupbyI assume).

Comment: @anky_91 as you said it's working on posted dataframe. Issue is that I did not anticipated in my dataset to have situation as blow:      
            A             B  C
    0  white  one  1
    1            2
    2  white  one  3
    3            4
    4            5
    5  white  one  6
    6  white  one  7    
Which give my such output:    
             A     B    C
    0        2 4 5
    1  white  one 1 3 6 7
Sorry I'm not sure how edit table in comment.

Comment: Thanks @anky_91. Initial test shows that solution is working, with one exception. With notnull() I get too much groups in groupby but removing this gives me satisfying results. Thanks.